# Can't build my project in release mode with linking

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, dotnetzip

Here is th exception I get when i try to run in release mode:

```
4>  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1124,3): error MSB4018: The "BuildApk" task failed unexpectedly. 
4>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1124,3): error MSB4018: System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added. 
4>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1124,3): error MSB4018:    at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource) 
4>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1124,3): error MSB4018:    at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add) 
4>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1124,3): error MSB4018:    at Ionic.Zip.ZipFile._InternalAddEntry(ZipEntry ze) 
4>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1124,3): error MSB4018:    at Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.AddFile(String fileName, String directoryPathInArchive) 
4>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1124,3): error MSB4018:    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.BuildApk.AddAssemblies(ZipFile apk) 
4>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1124,3): error MSB4018:    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.BuildApk.Execute() 
4>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1124,3): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
4>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1124,3): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__20.MoveNext()
```

Anyone have any suggestions how can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem with cleaning project.
Right-click on Project name -> Clean.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because it's trying to add two files with the same name to the archive. Check the XML of your project file for the duplicate. As an aside, it's likely that your project is actually displaying a file twice in the explorer and you've dismissed it as a anomaly or bug, so that might be a hint as to which file is the problem.

Comment: I checked my project file, and I can't find any duplicate file names. Although it's really strange that in debug mode everything is working fine. It's only happening if I add dotnetzip as a reference, and enable linking. If I remove dotnetzip and link it works. If I disable linking and has dotnetzip as reference it works.

Comment: Is this the stable version of `Mono for Android` or the beta version?